# Capture multiple images from camera

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way to capture multiple images from the camera activity without restarting the camera activity each time?

I'm aware, using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE it is possible to capture one image.  However, you only get one image and then the activity exits and my app resumes.

What I want is to use some intent, specify a directory where to save files, start the camera activity.  Then the user can take as many pictures as desired which will get saved to the specified directory (I can fall back on this requirement to saving in the default DCIM if necessary).  Finally, when the user is done, he taps "back" to return to my app. My app can then find all the new images in the specified directory.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent

Comment: You may be right.  There is absolutely zero Google documentation for this intent (although there are quite a few SO entries) so I'm not yet sure if if applies.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Here's another SO link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758710/onactivityresult-is-not-called-for-mediastore-intent-action-still-image-camera, that has a reasonably complete example.  It also uses INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA to start the camera and return to the app when the user is done.  (I presume tapping "back" will do that.)  Apparently it is not possible to specify a directory where images will be captured.